# Thumb or finger detection android

Tags: android, opencv, image-processing

I am working on heartbeat application. When you place your thumb or finger on top of camera it calculate user heartbeat So right now if you place anything on camera it starts to calculate it's heartbeat.

Now i want to put some detection on that so that it only calculate heartbeat when user place finger on it.

So how i can i achieve that? any guidance or help?

Comment: Can you tell us what you have so far?

Comment: I didn't tried anything so far :) i know opencv is there for that but i don't have idea where to start

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you will be able to detect the finger for 100% of the times .
But when a user puts hes finger on the camera you can check if the color is red'ish but then any thing red will be a positive detection (false positive).

Comment: what accuracy can i get?

Comment: If the user puts his finger on the camera you should be able to detect it (detect the red color). but you will get also false positives if the user puts any red thing on the camera.

Comment: I think that will work for me. I am not up to to achieve that much accuracy right now

Comment: check this: https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/tree/master/samples/android/color-blob-detection example for the color detection

Comment: Yes i got this from opencv sample. i am working on it. BTW what range of red color should i give

Comment: Don't know you need to test it.

Comment: Color code varies with outside light, Where you going to test. In brighter light, you will get the high values of Red avg but dim light you will get very low values for red. 

And one more thing I have tested it with different devices where moto g2 , levnovo k4 with marshmellow never cross the 100.  So putting check for red > 200 or red > 199 is useless.  we need  to search somthing else.